# how to configure gateway on centos(used google but no answers)

Tags: networking, centos, gateway

here are some configuration files from the virtualbox on centos5.5, i've restart the network,but also can't connect to the internet, no gateway records information listed using route command, however,while i typing "route add default gw 192.168.0.1" and it works well.how shoud i configurate the gateway ip? thanks in advance.

/etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

/etc/sysconfig/network

```
GATEWAY=192.169.0.1
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=localhost
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE="eth0"  
HWADDR="00:24:1D:8A:3D:F7" 
ONBOOT="yes"  
BOOTPROTO="static"  
BROADCAST="192.168.0.255"
NETWORY="192.168.0.1" 
IPADDR="192.168.0.109" 
NETMASK="255.255.0.0"
```

Comment: GATEWAY=192.169.0.1 - is this a typo in your question only, or is it in your /etc/sysconfig/network file too?

Comment: yes, this is a typo, actually,the GATEWAY is 192.168.0.1, but the network is not working.

Comment: NETWORY should be NETWORK

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 5 should have file route-eth0 (in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts )
put this string into it:
default X.X.X.X dev interface
make sure you change X.X.X.X and interface to your.

Btw, take a look to http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes.html